# Recursive function call conversion to lambda expression in Tree Implementation java

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, java-8

I took a case study for learning lambda expression of java 8 which is Generic N-array Tree Implementation.I have a recursive function to get the total number of nodes present in the tree.I am struck at this point.

```
public class GenericTree<T> {

private GenericTreeNode<T> root;

public GenericTree() {
    super();
}

public GenericTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
    return this.root;
}

public void setRoot(GenericTreeNode<T> root) {
    this.root = root;
}

public int getNumberOfNodes() {
    int numberOfNodes = 0;

    if(root != null) {
        numberOfNodes = getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(root) + 1; //1 for the root!
    }        

    return numberOfNodes;
}

private int getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(GenericTreeNode<T> node) {
    Integer numberOfNodes = node.getNumberOfChildren();

    for(GenericTreeNode<T> child : node.getChildren()) {
        numberOfNodes += getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(child);
    }        

    //node.getChildren().stream().map(child ->this.getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(child));

    //return node.getNumberOfChildren() + node.getChildren().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(GenericTree::getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc));        
}}
```

How to use lambda expression recursively to get the number of nodes instead of using the conventional approach mentioned in the code snippet?

Note : I went through multiple other questions,they provide simple factorial expression.So please provide some deeper insight on this

Comment: You are struck? By what? You appear to think that there's a question in there, but i don't see one.

Comment: apologies...if my phrasing is not prompt...The question is how to use lambda expression recursively to get the number of nodes instead of using the conventional approach mentioned in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is how to "translate" `getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc` to lambdas (the code seems correct so I guess it's what you're asking), a possible solution could be:

```
private int getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(GenericTreeNode<T> node) {
        return node.getNumberOfChildren() + node.getChildren().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Test::getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc));
    }
```

You'd have to change `Test` to the appropriate name of the class in order to make the method reference work.

You use [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) to make the reduction and get the number of nodes in the tree.

I guess it would be enough.

**UPDATE**

To solve the compiler error, you can try two approaches:

- making the `getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc` static (I guess isn't an option)
- Substitute the method reference by a lambda.

  ```
  private int getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(MyNode node) {
    return node.getNumberOfChildren() + node.getChildren().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(n - > getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(n)));
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the error states it Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc(GenericTreeNode) from the type GenericTree.

Comment: @karthik You're welcome. I've updated the answer with a possible solution, hope it works for you

Comment: You can use `this::getNumberOfnodeRecursiveFunc`…